# How would I sort this to alphabetically reversed?

Tags: sort, cut

I was wondering how I would get this to sort alphabetically but in reverse.
For ex. ( z-a )

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort
```

Comment: `sort --help` lists a whole bunch of neat options; `man sort` lists pretty much the same stuff

Answer (score 4):

You need to reverse in `sort` with `-r`.

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort -r
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort -r` is of course the best answer here but more generic and good to know is `tac` (`cat` reverse):

like this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort | tac
```